# django nested query or join two tables

Tags: python, django, rest, join, django-rest-framework

I list the debts of my customers from the "debts" table with the following code.

However, I would like to see the name and surname of the customer with the same ID number from the "Customer" table.

I get the person I specified with the following code but; I cannot print to "Debts.objects.values (" customer ")".

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

```
class CustomerDetailDebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        # get customer , customerKey
        obj_customer = Customer.objects.get(customer=85)
        field_object_customer = Customer._meta.get_field('customer')
        # field_value_customer = getattr(obj_customer, field_object_customer.attname)
        print(obj_customer)

        result = Debt.objects.values('customer') \
            .annotate(totalDebt=Sum('totalDebt'), receivedAmount=Sum('receivedAmount')) \
            .order_by('customer')
        return Response(result)
```

Comment: you can add nested value to DRF described in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am supposing that customer is a foreign key. You can access fields of your related tables using `__` operators. This is shown in below code

```
Debt.objects.all().annotate(totalDebt=Sum('totalDebt'), receivedAmount=Sum('receivedAmount')).order_by('customer').values('customer__surname')
```

or

```
from django.db.models import F
Debt.objects.all().annotate(totalDebt=Sum('totalDebt'), receivedAmount=Sum('receivedAmount'), surname=F('customer__surname')).order_by('customer').values('surname')
```